# Problem with parameters of ROOT TF1 function declaration

Tags: c++, data-analysis, root-framework

I use a user-defined function to fit a data set in ROOT. The TF1 class declaration in my code is:

```
double t=1000;
double a=0.1*t, b=0.9*t;
...
TF1 *ffit = new TF1("ffit",fit,a,b,2);
ffit->FixParameter(0,t);
ffit->SetParameter(1,1);
...
TGraph *g = new TGraph(n,x,y);
g->Fit("ffit","R");
```

I expect it will work, but actually it does not. There is a segmentation violation together with a mess appearing when I run this code. However, when I just put 100 and 900 instead of a and b in the declaration of TF1 function, it works well.

So, what is the problem here? How can I overcome this issue?
The function `fit` is as followed:

```
double fit(double *x, double *par) 
{ 
double y=par[0], g=par[1], y0=x[0];
double r=(y0*(y-y0))/y;  
return (pow(r,1.5)*g); 
}
```

P/s: I am using ROOT v6.14

Comment: That looks pretty similar to [the docs](https://root.cern/doc/v614/classTF1.html#F4), so I only have standard/blind guesses: can you also post the code for `fit`? or at least its signature? are you sure there's no issue inside of `fit`? Out of curiosity, when I look at the Fit docs [here](https://root.cern/doc/v614/classTGraph.html#aa978c8ee0162e661eae795f6f3a35589), you should also be able to run `g->Fit(ffit,"R")` w/o quotes, that could rule out name collisions?

Comment: I've just added the code for {fi}. I don't think there is something weird in the definition of {fit}. I did the change {g->Fit(ffit,"R")} as your suggestion, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) could be useful to try to help you. Also, this is maybe not the reason for the crash, but the fit function has 2 parameters which you both fix. So it is not a fit anymore. Is that intended?

Comment: @Keldorn Sorry for the mistake. Actually,I didn't fix the second parameter